# Pseudo Force on a block kept on a turntable

Tags: physics, orbital-mechanics

Let us consider two cases :

1. A block kept on a turntable and an observer standing by the block. ( as shown in [Fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJpsg.jpg) ) In this case, pseudo force on the block will be acting radially outwards so pseudo force = friction ( since block appears to be at rest )  .
2. Again a block is kept on a turntable and this time the observer is standing by the circumference making 90` with the line joining center an d block ( as shown in [Fig. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZxNh.jpg) ) . Now the friction provides the centripetal and as the acceleration on observer is radially inward so the pseudo force will be acted upon as shown in fig. 2 .

So, the question arises that which force is balancing the pseudo force in second case as the block still appears to be at rest ?

Comment: In the second case, the pseudo-force on the block is still radial outward.

Comment: What has the position of the observer to do with the force(s) acting on the block?